# How to close all Threads running in my java application?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, runnable

I want to close all thread which I started previously.

**Thread.currentThread()** gives me current thread, but what about others? How can I get them?

I think **Thread.activeCount()** returns the count of active threads in thread's  thread group, but I does not use **ThreadGroup**,
I just started threads using **Thread thread = new Thread(new MyRunnable())**.

So how can I achieve this?
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an ExecutorService instead which combines a thread pool with a queue of tasks.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
// or
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREADS);

// submit as many tasks as you want.
// tasks must honour interrupts to be stopped externally.
Future future = service.submit(new MyRunnable());

// to cancel an individual task
future.cancel(true);

// when finished shutdown
service.shutdown();
```

Comment: I want to run those threads individually for random time and then want to interrupt or stop them.
I think service.shutdown() will stop them after completion of all threads execution, Is it correct?

Comment: ExecutorService has a pool of threads which executing tasks. Submitted task will be executed before stopping the threads. From the docs: " Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted"

Comment: I have added an example of how to cancel&interrupt an individual task.

Comment: you can use `service.shutdownNow();` to kill the threads while processing.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply keep references to all the threads somewhere (like a list) and then use the references later.

```
List<Thread> appThreads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
```

Every time you start a thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
appThreads.add(thread);
```

Then when you want to signal termination (not via `stop` I hope :D) you have easy access to the threads you created.

You can alternatively use an `ExecutorService` and call shutdown when you no longer need it:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
...
exec.submit(new MyRunnable());
...
exec.shutdown();
```

This is better because you shouldn't really create a new thread for each task you want to execute, unless it's long running I/O or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to keep using the Thread object directly and not using ready-to-use thread services from [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) you should keep a references to all started thread (for example, put them in a List) and when wish to to close them, or interrupt them to stop, loop over the List.